# python regex: match a string with only one instance of a character

Tags: python, regex, string

Suppose there are two strings:

```
$1 off delicious ham.
$1 off delicious $5 ham.
```

In Python, can I have a regex that matches when there is only one $ in the string?  I.e., I want the RE to match on the first phrase, but not on the second.  I tried something like:

```
re.search(r"\$[0-9]+.*!(\$)","$1 off delicious $5 ham.")
```

..saying "Match where you see a $ followed by anything EXCEPT for another $."  There was no match on the $$ example, but there was also no match on the $ example.

Thanks in advance!

Simple test method for checking:

```
def test(r):
  s = ("$1 off $5 delicious ham","$1 off any delicious ham")    
  for x in s:
    print x
    print re.search(r,x,re.I)
    print ""
```

Comment: why not use the `.count()` method of the strings?

Comment: I'm shoe-horning an RE into a tool that doesn't let me add any additional logic.  So I can't do "if count(str,"$") > 1: pass".  I need the re to just not match on such a string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> onedollar = re.compile(r'^[^\$]*\$[^\$]*$')
>>> onedollar.match('$1 off delicious ham.')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fe253c9c4a8>
>>> onedollar.match('$1 off delicious $5 ham.')
>>>
```

Breakdown of regexp:
`^` Anchor at start of string
`[^\$]*` Zero or more characters that are not `$`
`\$` Match a dollar sign
`[^\$]*` Zero or more characters that are not `$`
`$` Anchor at end of string

Comment: Bonus points for the show-n-tell.  Do you have a couple minutes to describe to me what's going on, here?

Comment: 0 or more non dollars sign followed by one dollar followed by 0 or more non dollar sign

Comment: You don't need to escape the `$` inside a character class. `r'^[^$]*\$[^$]*$'` works just as well.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> '$1 off delicious $5 ham.'.count('$')
2
>>> '$1 off delicious ham.'.count('$')
1
```

Comment: I agree, a regular expression would be overkill here.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the *complement* of a character class `[^]` to match any character other than `$`:

```
re.match(r"\$[0-9]+[^\$]*$","$1 off delicious $5 ham.")
```

The changes from your original are as follows:

1. `.*` replaced with `[^\$]*`.  The new term `[^\$]` means any character other than `$`
2. `$` appended to string.  Forces the match to extend to the end of the string.
3. `re.search` replaced with `re.match`.  Matches the whole string, rather than any subset of it.

Comment: Didn't pass!

>>> test(r"\$[0-9]+[^\$]*$")
$1 off $5 delicious ham
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00ED65D0>

$1 off any delicious ham
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00ED65D0>

Answer (score 1):

```
re.search("^[^$]*\$[^$]*$",test_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*?\$[^$]*$
```

this should make the trick

Comment: nice use of a non-greedy match

Comment: Hmm.. Didn't pass the test, though, unless there are some special flags I need:
<pre>
    >>> test(r"^.*?\$[^$]*$")
    $1 off $5 delicious ham
    <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00ED6288>
    
    $1 off any delicious ham
    <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00ED6288>
    
</pre>