# Conditional Python regex to match URLs that may contain a second colon

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to match URLs or relative paths that do not contain a second colon (after the one in the protocol, e.g., `http(s)://`).

I want to reject URLs of the form

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0-8018-1841-9
```

or paths of the form

```
/wiki/Special:BookSources/0-8018-1841-9
```

with one exception. I want to keep the ones with a second colon *if* it is followed by an underscore:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Post_Card:_From_Socrates_to_Freud_and_Beyond
```

or

```
/wiki/The_Post_Card:_From_Socrates_to_Freud_and_Beyond`
```

The regex I have now (based on
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166619/python-regex-match-a-string-with-only-one-instance-of-a-character)) is `^[^:]*[:]*.*(/wiki/)[^:]+$`, which solves the first part of my requirement, but not the second.

How would I account for the special case of a colon followed by an underscore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A negative lookahead might make the most sense here:

```
^https?://(?!.*:[^_]).*wiki.*
```

Note that `/wiki/Special:BookSources/0-8018-1841-9` strictly, is not a URL because there is no protocol.  Rather, it is a path.  You may need to slightly modify what I wrote above, but the negative lookahead is an easy solution to your problem.

Comment: It won't accept "URLs with a second colon if it is followed by an underscore"

Comment: Updated to clarify URL vs. path. The regex provided satisfies both conditions: see [pythex demo](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5E.*(%3F!.*%3A%5B%5E_%5D).*wiki.*&test_string=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FThe_Post_Card%3A_From_Socrates_to_Freud_and_Beyond&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Answer (score 1):

When working with url paths that come in a variety of forms, different schemes, or without domain anchors, I like to use urlpath.

Installation:

```
pip install urlpath
```

You could use the urlpath library to check each of the parts of the url after the domain to see if they contain a colon without an underscore. This example is useful if you want to avoid regex.

Example:

```
>>> from urlpath import URL
>>> url = URL('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0-8018-1841-9')
>>> any(':' in i and not ':_' in i for i in url.parts[1:])
True
>>> url2 = URL('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Post_Card:_From_Socrates_to_Freud_and_Beyond')
>>> any(':' in i and not ':_' in i for i in url2.parts[1:])
False
```

In this example, the any statement are returning true for urls you want to ignore. If you want to make this example a little more functional, you can also filter using regex.

```
>>> any(re.search(':[^_]',i) for i in url.parts[1:])
True
>>> any(re.search(':[^_]',i) for i in url2.parts[1:])
False
```

If you are doing any request with these urls, I'd recommend giving the urlpath library a go. It combines the flexibility of pathlib, the functional urllib.parse, and has requests built it.

```
>>> url.get()
<Response [200]>
```